# Combine list and custom formula data validation in one cell within excel without vba

Tags: excel, validation

Can anyone help with a way of combining list and custom formula data validation in a single cell without using vba? I have a custom formula which validates the data if logical is TRUE but I want the user to have ability as well to select from a drop down list. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks.

Sorry if the question wasn't so clear enough. Please see below:

[image]

In this example, even though the user is able select from a dropdown list, if the user selects 7 for cell A2, the validation should throw out an error because it is not less than or equal to cell B2. Is it clearer?

Comment: You can construct the formula to perform the list check itself.

Comment: A lot more information would be needed for anyone to really help you.  What formula are you using?  Please show some data and expected outcome.

Comment: Also, please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ScottCraner, i completely understood the question, and i completely answered it below.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, can you explain or demo?

Comment: @johnywhy dude don't get cocky. I was trying to get more info because this was a poorly asked question.  Posters here are expected to show some effort to get help. I was just trying to get the OP to put in that required effort.

Comment: @ScottCraner, not being "cocky", just sharing that i had no trouble understanding the question. Nothing personal. Maybe it's because i'm an Excel dev, or maybe because i recently had a similar need. I think other Excel users who have a similar need will understand the question. Non-Excel users, and Excel users who don't have a similar need, might not understand the question, and i think that's ok. If i read a Java question, no matter how well-asked, i would not understand it, because i don't know java.

Comment: @johnywhy again it is not that I did not understand but was trying to draw out the op and get this to a decent question.  And I think my rep speaks to my excel abilities.

Answer (score 4):

This non-VBA solution combines a conditional with a dropdown picklist.
It provides 2 different picklists, dependent on value in another column.

This is *different* than the oft-shared [cascading-lists method](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/) (but do see the [link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/) for some great techniques)

Let's say you have a table with two columns. Field1 may contain anything:

```
a
box
cat
z
```

**Requirement:** Field2's validation should display List1 dropdown list when Field1 contains `a`, and display List2 when Field1 contains anything else.

**Solution:** Relies on the fact that an Excel conditional formula can return a *range* containing a list of items.

**Steps:**

- Create a list of picklist-values on a lookup-sheet, and name it `List1`.
- Create another list on the lookup-sheet, and name it `List2`.
- On your entry-sheet, insert a Table object containing 2 columns. Name the table `MyTable`, and the fields `Field1` and `Field2`.

  [image]
- Create the following defined name, and call it `ValidFmla`. This is the secret sauce:

  `=IF(MyTable[@Field1]="a", List1, List2)`
- Select the entry-cells in Field2, and click Validation on the data-ribbon.
- Choose "List" type, and enter `=ValidFmla`
- test it out:

  [image][image]

**Benefits:**

- It will not break if you change your table name, field names, list-names, or validation-formula name-- all dependent stuff updates automatically.
- supports any complex conditions you want, as long as your validation formula returns a list-range. Validation does not have to be based on the values in Field1.
- the validation list-ranges can be named anything. the dependent-lists method requires naming the validation list-ranges the same as the values in the first field.

Note, you do *not* have to use a Table object to use this method. But, using the Table object provides structured-referencing in the validation formula, which is a smarter, more readable way to build formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Save we want to setup *DV* in cell **B1** so:

- if a *number* is entered, it must be less than the value in **A1**
- if *text* is entered, it must be in the list from **D1** through**D3**

Here is the formulaic *DV* to do that:

[image]

The formula combines numeric tests with the ability to restrict input to some fixed list.

Comment: The list I am referring to is such that the user can select input from a drop down and yet the logical test will still be conducted. I don't want user to type in the value, I want him/her to select it.

Comment: @TundeAwosanya, see my answer, i believe it's correct and complete.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is older, but for completeness I am also going to offer another solution that is non-VBA.  The OP I don't believe was seeking methods to provide dependent lists as per most of the solutions offered, instead he wants his options list to exist as-is and instead provide additional validation on the actual selection being performed.

This actually needs to use a different feature of Excel to provide this insight to yourself easier.  Conditional Formatting. As per the OP's screenshot provided originally:

Highlight column A, click Conditional Formatting (Home Tab for me) > New Rule. Select the last option, custom formula one, and use the formula:

```
=$A1>$B1
```

Click Formatting button, change the background or some other colouring so the validation is made obvious, click OK.  See screenshot for results, you still setup your data validation list as per normal for the user to select values from. One thing to note, is that this does not stop the input, it merely provides a visual confirmation that the input is wrong.

[Screenshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj525.png)